# Is there a python implementation of a basis pursuit solver?

Tags: python, optimization, minimization

Originally, I wanted to use the [YALL1 package](https://www.caam.rice.edu/~zhang/reports/tr0917.pdf) for L1 minimization, however, it's written in matlab. After some research I couldn't find a [basis pursuit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basis_pursuit) solver in Python but is there one out there? Alternatively, which existing libraries can I use to solve this minimization problem?

Here's the original problem (BP+):

[image: Imgur]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you can do basis pursuit using quadratic cone programming ([quick reference](https://www.math.ucla.edu/~wotaoyin/summer2013/slides/Lec02_BasicSparseOptimizationModels.pdf)).

In python you can use [cvxopt to solve quadratic cone programs](https://cvxopt.org/userguide/coneprog.html#quadratic-cone-programs)

Edit: it is even [one of their examples](https://cvxopt.org/examples/book/basispursuit.html).

Answer (score 2):

As noticed in the original paper [Atomic Decomposition by Basis
Pursuit](https://web.stanford.edu/group/SOL/papers/BasisPursuit-SIGEST.pdf) about Basis Pursuit (BP), the BP can be equivalently reformulated as linear programming (LP) problem, and LP has developed very efficient solvers.

In [this se.math site](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1639716/how-can-l-1-norm-minimization-with-linear-equality-constraints-basis-pu) there is a discussion and a formula for standard form of LP problem given BP problem. Recall that in BP, you are looking for `x` with shape `(x_dim, )` such that `A@x=y` and `x` is minimal regards to L1 norm. Thus, you need just a script which takes array `A` with shape `(y_dim, x_dim)`, `y` with shape `(y_dim, )` and returns standard form.

Here is the function which takes BP problem and returns optimal `x` using standard form for LP (I have written it in such way so that it fits to the terminology used in [that tutorial](https://realpython.com/linear-programming-python/)). The script uses `scipy.optimize.linprog` as a backend for LP.

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import linprog

def get_optimal_x_for_bp(A, y):
    x_dim, y_dim = A.shape[1], y.shape[0]
    eye = np.eye(x_dim)

    obj = np.concatenate([np.zeros(x_dim), np.ones(x_dim)])

    lhs_ineq = np.concatenate([np.concatenate([eye, -eye], axis=1), np.concatenate([-eye, -eye], axis=1)], axis=0)
    rhs_ineq = np.zeros(2 * x_dim)

    lhs_eq = np.concatenate([A, np.zeros((y_dim, x_dim))], axis=1)
    rhs_eq = y

    bnd = [*((None, None) for _ in range(x_dim)), *((0, None) for _ in range(x_dim))]

    res = linprog(c=obj, A_ub=lhs_ineq, b_ub=rhs_ineq, A_eq=lhs_eq, b_eq=rhs_eq, bounds=bnd, method="revised simplex")
    return res.x[:x_dim]
```

You can check that it works properly on the example `2x_1-x_2=2`:

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    A = np.array([[2, -1]])
    y = np.array([2])

    x = get_optimal_x_for_bp(A, y)
    print(x)
Output: [1. 0.]
```

The output says that `x_1=1, x_2=0` is the optimal `x`. It is true as you can see from the following image:
[image]

You can also apply it to some more complex problems:

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    x_dim, y_dim = 6, 4

    A = np.random.rand(y_dim, x_dim)
    y = np.random.rand(y_dim)

    x = get_optimal_x_for_bp(A, y)
    print(x)
Output: [ 0.          1.55953519  0.50597071  0.          0.1724968  -1.86814744]
```

Just keep in mind, that as it is written in the original paper about BP, the system `A@x=y` should be overcomplete.